# passport.deserializeUser only working when not passing 'id' through 'getUserById'

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

At first the serialize/deserialize section of my code looked like this

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'email' }, authenticateUser))
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => done(null, user.id))
passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
   return done(null, getUserById(id))
});
```

But after I logged in `req.user` returned `Promise { <pending> }`. So I then tried changing my code to this

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'email' }, authenticateUser))
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => done(null, user.id))
passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
   getUserById(id).then(user => {
      done(null, user);
   }).catch(err => {
   console.log(err)
      done(err);
   });
})
```

I hoped attaching a `.then().catch()` to the promise would solve the issue but at then I couldn't log in and I realized that printing `getUserById(id)` returned `null`. After messing around and trying different things I realized that the code works as intended when I simple don't pass `id` into `getUserById()`. But surely this can't be a good thing right?

*side note: printing `id` always returned the logged in users id*

Here's my the rest of my initialize function

```
function initialize(passport, getUserByEmail, getUserById) {
    const authenticateUser = async (email, password, done) => {
        const user = await getUserByEmail(email)
        console.log(email)
        if (user == null) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect email or password' })
    }
    try {
        if (await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)) {
        return done(null, user)
    } else {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect email or password' })
    }
    } catch (e) {
        return done(e)
    }
}
```

And finally where I define the email and id, back in the index.js

```
const initializePassport = require('../passport-config')
initializePassport(
    passport,
    async (email) => await User.findOne({email: email}),
    async (id) => await User.findOne({id: id})
)
```

I'd be very grateful if anyone could point out why I'm having this issue trying to deserialize my user the correct way. This is my first time doing any kind of back end coding and even just getting this far has been quite the journey.

Comment: It sounds like you are having issues with `getUserById` which in turn is effecting `deserializeUser`. Can you share the code for `getUserById` or are you pulling it from mongoose?

Comment: Yes, I'm using mongoose. I have a `userSchema` that just takes a name, email and password @jasonandmonte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using a `User` object to perform queries, but in `deserializeUser` you are just using a function called `getUserById`. Its unclear to me if this is a custom wrapper for your User model, but for getting an id you can use `.findById`.

I would recommend updating the block to use a User object to query the database. You can also keep things flatter by using async/await, but it should work with .then as well.

Example:

```js
passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => {
  const user = await User.findById(id);
   return done(null, user);
});
```

Model reference: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById

Comment: Thank you so much! That works perfectly. I'm a little embarrassed it was something so silly that I was getting wrong but I suppose that's what I deserve when following a tutorial that was storing the user locally instead of using mongoose haha.
I was originally using async/await too but a friend told me a `.then()` and `.catch()` was better for catching errors which kind of made sense to me